# Backbone.js from 0.9.2 up to 0.9.9, error occur "Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined"

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to use the argument {patch:true} in my website.
But our Backbone.js is **0.9.2**, it need update to **0.9.9**,
I just copy the two files into my /lib folder

> Backbone.js
>
> Backbone.min.js

But error occur "Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined"
what can i do in this issue?

```
VM46:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined
at child.eval (eval at b.template (underscore.min.js:30), <anonymous>:8:3)
at child.c [as template] (underscore.min.js:30)
at child.render (mainApp.js:83)
at mainApp.js:283
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Function.b.each.b.forEach (underscore.min.js:11)
at child.Collection.(anonymous function) [as each] (http://192.168.0.1/webpages/lib/thirdparty/backbone.js:940:24)
at child.showMenus (mainApp.js:281)
at triggerEvents (backbone.js:98)
at child.trigger (backbone.js:186)
```

[function anonymous here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POUFV.jpg)

> My Jquery version : 1.8.3
>
> My Underscore version : 1.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to [0.9.9 docs](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/0.9.9/index.html):

> Backbone's only hard dependency is either Underscore.js ( > 1.4.3) or Lo-Dash. For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include json2.js, and either jQuery ( > 1.4.2) or Zepto.

It seems you have old underscore version than required.

If the error is from your custom code then adjust it according to [change log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) of 0.9.9